# Ruby on Rails ENV['RAILS_ENV'] returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the current environment I'm working on with rails using ENV['RAILS_ENV'] but it returns nil. Does anyone know why? I get an environment when I run the Rails.env script but I need to use ENV['RAILS_ENV'] in my environment.rb file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead (rails 3 not sure about earlier versions)

```
Rails.env
```

or

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development"
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use

```
Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.test?
```